# how to import excel password file into python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am importing excel password file into python and it's showing this error: `No module named win32api`. I've already installed `pypiwin32`.

```
import sys
import win32com.client

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
print "Excel library version:", xlApp.Version
filename,password = 'C:\Users\Ebase\Documents\PASSW.xlsx', '123456'
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ebase\Documents\PASSW.xlsx", False, True, None, "123456")

print(xlwb)
```

code here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Excel_wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)
```

It worked for me.

If this doesn't work,
Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) for more details about the `Open()` method

Open takes two types of password, namely:

```
Password: password required to open a protected workbook.
WriteResPassword : password required to write to a write-reserved workbook
```

So in your case , is it write protected or protection on open?

To open reserved excel file try:

```
app.Workbooks.Open("filename.xls", 2, True, None, None, "secret")
```

Comment: showing error in importing files .what are the files require to import to run the code .i already installed pywin32

Comment: You have to pass absolute path to win32, when you open the excel file,Not relative path..

Comment: What error showing..?, did you close excel application at end `xlwb.Save()` and `xlApp.Application.Quit()`